# Unity.BuildUp unable to disambiguate

Tags: unity-container

I have a class with two constructors, both constructors have one parameter.  Due to restrictions not worth explaining I cannot alter the constructors or use a descendent class.

I can't use unity to create instances of this class because Unity sees 2 constructors with the same number of parameters and complains that it doesn't know which to use, which is fair enough.  So instead I create the instance myself and then try to use UnityContainer.BuildUp()

```
var result = constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { content });
UnitContainer.BuildUp(result);
```

The above code does not set any of my [Dependency] properties nor does it call an [InjectionMethod] if I use that instead.

```
var result = constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { content });
UnitContainer.BuildUp(typeOfObject, result);
```

This throws another exception about ambiguous constructors, even though I am not asking it to construct the instance.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is an example app

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    public interface IConstructorType1 { }
    public interface IConstructorType2 { }
    public interface INeedThisDependency { }
    public class NeedThisDependency : INeedThisDependency { }

    public class MyDomainObject
    {
        public MyDomainObject(IConstructorType1 constructorType1) { }
        public MyDomainObject(IConstructorType2 constructorType2) { }

        [Dependency]
        public INeedThisDependency Needed { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
            unityContainer.RegisterType<INeedThisDependency, NeedThisDependency>();
            //Try with type 1 constructor
            ConstructorInfo constructorInfo1 = typeof(MyDomainObject).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IConstructorType1) });
            MyDomainObject instance1 = CreateTheInstance(unityContainer, typeof(MyDomainObject), constructorInfo1, null);
            //Try with type 2 constructor
            ConstructorInfo constructorInfo2 = typeof(MyDomainObject).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IConstructorType2) });
            MyDomainObject instance2 = CreateTheInstance(unityContainer, typeof(MyDomainObject), constructorInfo2, null);
        }

        //This is the only point I have any influence over what happens
        //So this is the only place I get to change the code.
        static MyDomainObject CreateTheInstance(IUnityContainer unityContainer, Type type, ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, object parameters)
        {
            var result = (MyDomainObject)constructorInfo.Invoke(new object[] { parameters });
            //This will throw an ambiguous constructor exception,
            //even though I am not asking it to construct anything
            unityContainer.BuildUp(type, result);
            //This will not build up dependencies
            unityContainer.BuildUp(result); 
            if (result.Needed == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException("Needed");
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is an Interceptor defined for that type? That could cause such a behvaiour in the BuildUp Method!

Comment: No, I have no interceptors or anything at all like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling BuildUp call this CallInjectionMethod helper.

```
public static class UnityContainerHelper
{
    public static void CallInjectionMethod(this IUnityContainer unityContainer, object instance, params ResolverOverride[] overrides)
    {
        if (instance == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Instance");

        var injectionMethodInfo = instance.GetType().GetMethods().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(InjectionMethodAttribute), true).Any()).SingleOrDefault();
        if (injectionMethodInfo == null)
            return;
        var parameters = injectionMethodInfo.GetParameters();
        if (parameters.Length == 0)
            return;

        var dependencies = new object[parameters.Length];
        int index = 0;
        foreach (Type parameterType in parameters.Select(x => x.ParameterType))
        {
            dependencies[index] = unityContainer.Resolve(parameterType, overrides);
            index++;
        }
        injectionMethodInfo.Invoke(instance, dependencies);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in BuildUp, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Chris. I've added a helper method to call the object's injection method.